# Is Dijkstra's Algorithm symmetrical?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

In Dijkstra Algorithm to find the shortest path in a positively weighted graph, can there be a scenario in which the route A -> B does not equal the route B -> A? (A and B are vertexes on a graph). Can you provide an example?

Comment: If the graph is undirected and the shortest path is unique, then no - both directions will produce the same path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the graph is not directional, the set of shortest paths from `A` to `B` (`S_{ab}`) is the same as set of shortest paths from `B` to `A` (`S_{ba}`). You can prove it by the contradiction.

Suppose it is not. So there is at least one path `P` from `B` to `A` which is not in the `S_{ab}`. 
As the graph is not directional, there is the same path from `A` to `B`. If the length of the path is greater than all path in `S_{ab}`, so it is not shortest path from `B` to `A`, as you can return from `B` to `A` with one of path in shortest path in `S_{ab}`.

Also, if the length of `P` is less than length of paths in `S_{ab}`, so we can go from `A` to `B` with less than the cost of all path in `S_{ab}`. Hence, `P` must be in `S_{ab}` by the definition of the set. But, it is contradicted by the assumption. Hence, it is not possible.